# Deeply nested unevaluatedProperties and their expectations

Tags: jsonschema

I have been working on my own validator for JSON schema and FINALLY have most of how unevaluatedProperties are supposed to work,... I think. That's one tricky piece there! However I really just want to confirm one thing. Given the following schema and JSON, what is the expected outcome... I have tried it with a https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net and gotten an answer, but I was hoping I could get a more definitive answer.

The focus is the faz property is in fact being evaluated, but the command to disallow unevaluatedProperties comes from a deeply nested schema.

Thoguhts?

Here is the schema...

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "bar": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "unevaluatedProperties": false
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "properties": {
            "faz": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the JSON...

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "test",
    "faz": "test"
  }
}
```

Comment: We have a channel on the JSON Schema Slack for implemeters. It's a great place to ask this kind of question and reach a others that have have implemented or are implementing validators and other tooling. https://json-schema.org/slack

Comment: Also, if you haven't found it yet, there is an official test suite with a bunch of examples of correct behavior. https://github.com/json-schema-org/JSON-Schema-Test-Suite/

Answer (score 0):

That schema will successfully evaluate against the provided data. The `unevaluatedProperties` keyword will be aware of properties evaluated in subschemas of adjacent keywords, and is evaluated after all other applicator keywords, so it will see the annotation produced from within the `anyOf` subschema, also.

Evaluating this keyword is easy if you follow the specification literally -- it uses annotations to decide what to do. You just need to make sure that all keywords either produce annotations correctly or propagate annotations correctly that were produced by other keywords, and then all the information is available to generate the correct result.

The result produced by [my implementation](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Schema::Draft201909) is:

```
{
  "annotations" : [
    {
      "annotation" : [
        "faz"
      ],
      "instanceLocation" : "/foo",
      "keywordLocation" : "/anyOf/0/properties/foo/properties"
    },
    {
      "annotation" : [
        "foo"
      ],
      "instanceLocation" : "",
      "keywordLocation" : "/anyOf/0/properties"
    },
    {
      "annotation" : [
        "bar"
      ],
      "instanceLocation" : "/foo",
      "keywordLocation" : "/properties/foo/properties"
    },
    {
      "annotation" : [],
      "instanceLocation" : "/foo",
      "keywordLocation" : "/properties/foo/unevaluatedProperties"
    },
    {
      "annotation" : [
        "foo"
      ],
      "instanceLocation" : "",
      "keywordLocation" : "/properties"
    }
  ],
  "valid" : true
}
```

Comment: So to be clear you disagree with the result of https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net because it fails the example I provided. It appears to only track the immediate schema where unevaluatedProperties is defined. I have not tried other validators so not a great sample base.

Comment: For those who want to know how I am testing...

1. Determine if the validator even supports the unevaluatedProperties keyword by testing various scenarios where I know it should or should not work.
2. If it does not then do not use that validator. If it does then move to step 3.
3. Get a result with the above example.

So far I have tested a few different online options. Most do appear to even recognize the unevaluatedProperties keyword. In fact the only one appears to is https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net.

Comment: I just tested with AJV. It also provides a failing result. I can post the code if you want. I tested node v11.10.1

Comment: The example should fail validation. The `anyOf` doesn't come into play because it's in a different branch of the schema than the `unevaluatedProperties` keyword. `unevaluatedProperties` can see sub-schemas, but not parent-schemas.

Comment: I disagree. The subschema(s) below `/properties` see the annotations produced by `/anyOf`, which allows `unevaluatedProperties` to pass. If sibling schemas could not see each others' annotations, how could `/properties/foo/unevaluatedProperties` see the annotations from `/properties/foo/properties`?

Comment: `/properties/foo/unevaluatedProperties` can see the annotations from `/properties/foo/properties` because they are in the same schema.

Comment: I'm preparing a PR to add some cases to the official test suite that covers this.

Comment: Not to add fuel to the fire but I have another example which I feel is in the same vein. I will post it as an answer though.

Comment: PR created: https://github.com/json-schema-org/JSON-Schema-Test-Suite/pull/472